# For every natural n, construct a series of n consecutive numbers that are composite of at least two different primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, chinese-remainder-theorem

Consider the following problem:

> For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a series $a_1,...,a_n$ of **consecutive numbers** s.t. $\forall i. a_i$ is not a power of a prime number (its factorization exists of at least 2 different primes)

Does the following solution hold?

*$x\equiv0(2)$*

$x\equiv0(3)$

$x+1\equiv0(5)$

$x+1\equiv0(7)$

$...$

$x+(n-1)\equiv0(p_{2n-1})$

$x+(n-1)\equiv0(p_{2n})$

And then construct the series $x,x+1,...,x+(n-1)$

Using the Chinese remainder theorem, there exists a solution. Because each member of the series is congruent to 0 modulu two different prime numbers, it must be a composite of at least 2 different primes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  Why not just list the primes $2=p_1<3=p_2 < p_3 <... < p_{n+1}$ and take $a_i=p_i p_{i+1}$?

Comment: I don't know if your solution is correct or not but it seems a trivial question and there are much easier ways to solve it.  As there are infinite primes we can find p_1 = 2, p_2=3,...... p_n.  Just do a_n = 2p_(n+1) or a_n = p_np_(n+1) or just about any other obvious answer.  Why do something as hard as you are attempting.  Or more subtle as there are infinite composites that aren't powers of prime just list them as c_1 = 6, c_2=10,c_3=12.... and let a_n = c_n?  That *is* a legitimate answer.  (If you prove there are infinite such numbers ... which is trivial to do...)

Comment: Here's a cute one:  $a_n = 2*3^n$.  Or $a_n = n!$ or... there's gazillions of 'em for gob's sake!

Comment: Oh wow, I completely forgot that the numbers need to be consecutive. As in $a, a+1, ..., a+(n-1)$

Comment: Hmm, looks good to me.  And very clever.   (Maybe you should write $x = 4 mod 5$ and $x = 6 mod 7$ and $x = p_{2n} - 1 + n mod p_{2n}$ to make this agree with the standard form of the chinese remainder thereom.   Or maybe that's trivial...)

Comment: The standard way is to claim (n+1)! + 2 through (n+1)! + (n+1) are composite.  I think it requires very little more to prove that if p|(n+1)! + p that (n+1)!/p + 1 is not equal to p^{k-1}.  Although maybe it isn't as easy to prove a it looks.  Still I can't find any problem with your method.

Comment: @fleablood $5!+5$ just happens to be a prime power, so no luck.

Comment: @IvanNeretin  Hmmm, so it is.  $5!/5 + 1 = 2*3*4  + 1 = (5 + 1)(5 -1) +1 = 5^2.$  But that's got to be fairly anomalous.   $(p-2)! = (p^{k-1} + .... + 1)$ can not happen for any other  $p > 5$.  And $(n+1)! + p^k = p^m$ can't have happen if if $k > 1$ and $n + 1 \ge 2p$.  Can $(p-1)!*(n+1)!/p! + 1 = p^k$ for $p > 5$.  I don't know.  Maybe.  But I doubt it.  Still the chinese remainder th. answer is clever.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's an easy problem. Powers are rare (prime powers even more so), hence there are arbitrarily large gaps between them, which can be proven in a multitude of ways. Your solution is totally OK. Here is another: let's see how many powers are there below some huge $N$. (Let's be generous and consider all of them, not just prime powers.) Apparently, there are no more than $\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt[3]N\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt[4]N\rfloor+\dots$ of them, which is less than $\log_2N\cdot\sqrt N$, which means that the largest gap between them is bounded from below with ${N\over\log_2N\cdot\sqrt N}={\sqrt N\over\log_2N}$, which can be made arbitrarily large.